# SQL Return subquery 'Total Records' to outer query

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, subquery

This one has me a little stumped, I'm trying to get the total count in my top (root) node XML from this SQL query:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) OVER() as '@totalCount', (
        SELECT COUNT(*) OVER() as totalCount, [Title], [Year], [Type], [Poster]
        FROM movies As result where CONTAINS(Title, @Title) Order by [Weight] DESC
        OFFSET ((@PageNumber - 1) * @RowspPage) ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @RowspPage ROWS ONLY
        FOR XML AUTO, type
    ) 
    FOR XML PATH('root')
```

Obviously the `COUNT(*)` `OVER()` is only returning "1" because it's being executed at the top level and not within the subquery. But I only want to display it once in the root node and not repeat per each result.

[image: result of code]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fun with strings... This is a total hack, but it works:

```
DECLARE @totalCount AS INT
DECLARE @result varchar(MAX)

SELECT @totalCount = COUNT(*) OVER(), @result = COALESCE(@result + '', '') + '<result title="' + [Title] + '" year="' + [Year] + '" type="' + [Type] + '"/>'
FROM Movies where CONTAINS(Title, '@Title') Order by [Weight] DESC
OFFSET ((@PageNumber - 1) * @RowspPage) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @RowspPage ROWS ONLY
SELECT '<root totalCount="' + CAST(@totalCount AS VARCHAR) + '">' + @result + '</root>'
```

Output:

[image]

Seems to have a faster/more efficient execution plan as the calculation is only made once and no additional queries to any tables are required.

Comment: I'm glad, that you found a solution! But be aware, that this string concatenation approach `SELECT @variable=@variable + ...` is not absolutely reliable and - concerning long strings - is **very** bad performing normally. I'm quite sure, that there is one way to get the result of `COUNT(*) OVER()` and use it the same way as pointed in my answer. But nevermind, happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Here a working example with common data to walk along:

```
;with myCTE as
(
    select *
    from sys.objects
)
select (select count(*) from myCTE) as [@Counter]
    ,(
       SELECT myCTE.object_id AS id
             ,mycte.name AS name 
       from myCTE
       for xml path('object'),TYPE
      )       
for xml path('test')
```

You might try to shift your query into a CTE and put it to something like this:

```
;WITH MyQueryAsCTE AS
(
    SELECT [Title], [Year], [Type], [Poster]
    FROM movies As result where CONTAINS(Title, @Title) Order by [Weight] DESC
    OFFSET ((@PageNumber - 1) * @RowspPage) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @RowspPage ROWS ONLY
)
SELECT  (SELECT Count(*) FROM MyQueryAsCTE) as '@totalFound'
       ,[Title] AS [Movie/Title] 
       ,[Year] AS [Movie/Year]
       ,[Type] AS [Movie/Type]
       ,[Poster] AS [Movie/Poster]
FROM MyQueryAsCTE
FOR XML PATH('root')
```

Comment: That almost did the trick! It returned "10" however, which is how many results I'm limiting the query to return from the Offset/Fetch...

Comment: @bfritz Hi, I edited my answer with an common-data example. This should  lead you the way...

Comment: @bfritz, Your idea to  wrap the second select in paranthesis and call it with  `FOR XML PATH ... , TYPE` was correct obviously...

Comment: as soon as I introduce the paging techniques (Offset/Fetch) it's only returning the amount I'm suppressing the query to and not the total.

Comment: @bfritz Ah OK, just change the "SELECT Count(*)..." to a `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Movies)` This should get the full count.

Comment: Not quiet, doing a count(*) on Movies just gives me the 1.3 million records count and not the findings of the FULL-TEXT CONTAINS() Search.

Comment: @bfritz, so you need to repeat the where there to get the correct count. You might use the CTE without the Offset-Fetch, use this count and put the Offset-Fetch in the main SELECT.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101068/discussion-between-bfritz-and-shnugo).